Pi with LED Matrix not working properly
I've bought a 64x64 LED Matrix Display, an Adafruit bonnet and a Raspberry Pi 4 2Gb.
I have set everything up and tested the Display and set all pixels to red. But only the first and the third quarter of the display turn red. the second and fourth quarter is not set.
I have connected the bonnet and the display via the white 16 pin cable. If im pressing on the cable (not even moving it; just pressing) some pixels also display on the second and fourth quarter of the display.
Why is that? Should I return the display?

Contact Adafruit.

how do you know that the first and third quarters are not displaying the same data? ... use different colors

Why is that? ... that depends on what you have ... you said nothing about the display, the cable, or about the bonnet

Would be much better if you linked to exactly what you have. And where you got your Raspberry Pi operating system and display application from. We don't know what OS you are running let alone what application you are using to display images on your LED matrix. We don't even know what you expect to see on your LED matrix.

If you have another 16-pin ribbon cable, swap it out to see if the problem persists. Check the 16-pin header on the bonnet for bent or damaged pins. Also, see if the solder joints on the bonnet are intact. Insufficient or unstable power can cause unpredictable behaviour. Check if your Raspberry Pi is powered by an adequate power supply. 5V, 3A is recommended for the Pi 4. If you want to design a new LED matrix, you can see here: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Bluetooth_Controlled_LED_Matrix_Design_c5196681.html

WRT power vcgencmd get_throttled should yield throttled=0x0; if not https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html#get_throttled
